# Update method in laravel are going to create a new model in database

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am facing a problem in laravel restful api building,

I have the following controller

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Kittrans;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Inventory;
 use App\Kittrans;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

 class KittransController extends Controller
 {

 public function index()
 {

 }
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

     $rules =[
    'kmo_id' => 'required',
    'item_id' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    'store_id' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    'count' => 'required|integer|min:1'
    ];

    $this->validate($request,$rules);

    // check if requested count of item less than or equal to count in store
    $inventory = DB::table('inventories')->where(
        [
        ['item_id','=',$request->input('item_id')],
        ['store_id','=',$request->input('store_id')]
        ]
        )->get();

    if($inventory->count()!=1)
    {
         return response()->json(['Error'=>'Model not found'],404);
    }

    $remaining = $inventory->get(0)->count;

    if($request->input('count') > $remaining)
    {
        return response()->json(['Error'=>'Request item count should be less than in the selected store!'],422);
    }


    // get user id bu auth. but for now i will make it static to complete first version of api 
    testing
    $request['user_id'] = 1;
    $newModel = Kittrans::create($request->all());

    $remaining = $remaining - $request->input('count');
    Inventory::where('id',$inventory->get(0)->id)->update(array('count' => $remaining));

    return response()->json($newModel,200);

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Kittrans $kittrans)
{
    //
    return response()->json($kittrans,200);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Kittrans $kittrans)
{

    $kittrans->fill($request->only([
        'item_id',
        'kmo_id',
        'count'
        ]));

    if($kittrans->isClean())
    {
        return response()->json(['Error'=>'You should make some changes in your values to update'],422);
    }

    $kittrans->save();
    return response()->json($kittrans,200);
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Kittrans $kittrans)
{
    //

 $kittrans->delete();

 return response()->json($kittrans,200);
}
}
```

and route/api.php as following :

```
Route::resource('kittrans','Kittrans\KittransController',['except'=>['index']]);
```

when i make a request to update the object in database the problem is a new model will be inserted into the table with $kittrans->save() method!!

why like this issue happening?

my request from postman look like this :

URL : myApp.test/kittrans/5003

method : put,patch

Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data : item_id,kmo_id,count

Also i have added 
`dd($kittrans);` before save() method and i got the following :

```
Kittrans {#345
#fillable: array:4 [
0 => "count"
1 => "kmo_id"
2 => "item_id"
3 => "user_id"
]
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: false
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:3 [
"item_id" => "1"
"kmo_id" => "1"
"count" => "7"
]
#original: []
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
```

why save method are going to create a new instance of model in db?
i have implement update method in all other controllers and everything is ok, but for this controller i don't understand where is the problem?

Comment: If you do `dd($kittrans);` in your `update()` function, what do you get? (Add that to your question, don't post it in the comments). It's likely that `$kittrans` isn't an instance of an existing record, but an instance none-the-less, which means `save()` is going to save a new record. I've seen this issue with route model binding, but I'm not sure how you'd fix it.

Comment: Hi @TimLewis dd($kittrans) after the save method? or before?

Comment: Before the `save()` method; you need to see what it is before it's saved.

Comment: Can you please paste the exact URL that you are using in Postman?

Comment: @TimLewis
I edited my post with using dd($kittrans)
could you see it again please?

Comment: @Vladan
Hi Vladan,
Edited my post and i added the URL with the details of the request

Comment: Yup, and as I expected `+exists: false` is set on that instance of `Kittran`, meaning it doesn't exist in the database. Thought I had the solution, but no; you model is named `Kittrans`, so it wasn't that (it should be singular though, `Kittran`). I'm not sure what's up here, since I don't use Model binding/injection, but that's the core issue.

Comment: I don't think the problem in the name of resource
Model Name is : Kittrans ('s' is not mean a plural) ,
also store method work correctly, and the id (5003) of model also exist in the table in db

Comment: @TimLewis
You saved me, Really the problem was in model name should not end with 's',
thank you

Comment: Yeah, name _shouldn't_ be the issue then, as long as they match (in resource and actual model name). And yes, I believe 5003 exists in the database, but `POST`ing to `myApp.test/kittrans/5003` is not properly translating `5003` to `Kittrans $kittrans`; it should be returning an instance with `id: 5003`, and if it can't find that, it should be a 404. Again, I can't really say why this is happening (sorry), just that I can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter for your controller method for the model binding isn't named correctly.

Your route parameter is `kittran` not `kittrans`; resource routing will use the singular name of the resource for the route parameter. You have to match that name for the binding:

```
public function update(Request $request, Kittrans $kittran)
```

Without that match you are just getting a new model instance injected instead of a model binding happening.

You can run the `route:list` command to see how your routes are being defined:

```
php artisan route:list
```

> "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name." - [Laravel 6.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Bindings - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#implicit-binding)
>
> "By default, `Route::resource` will create the route parameters for your resource routes based on the "singularized" version of the resource name." - [Laravel 6.x Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers - Naming Resource Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

If you want to override this behavior, for this resource, and use `kittrans` as the parameter name you can also do that, then you wouldn't need to change your controller method's signature:

```
Route::resource('kittrans', 'Kittrans\KittransController', [
    'except'=> ['index'],
    'parameters' => ['kittrans' => 'kittrans'],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you model binding is not correct, when you model binding is wrong the Kittrans object will be empty and not saved to the db, when you fill and save it will save a new object. To solve your wrong model binding add this to the `RouteServiceProvider.php`.

```
use App\Kittrans;

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('kittrans', Kittrans::class);
}
```